# Dart, Polymer and Foundation CSS

Tags: dart, zurb-foundation, dart-polymer

I tried mixing polymer web component w/dart and Foundation CSS framework and so far things simple things are working like button, grid, menu.  I guess if i run into an issue, I just need to port the javascript I need to dart.  Anyone try this or thinking of trying this?

This was trick to get CSS to leak into component.

```
class ClickCounter ... {
...
  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;
...
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNoGR.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes I try this too.
The first thing I tried was create one style file for each component and use the sass @extends to make each component style, my goal was to abstract the zurb, so if I want change the theme, or css framework I just need change the sass file.

But zurb-foundation depends on a base file that have to be include, I can't create one file just for buttons, because de buttons in foundation depend on variables seted in the main file, this generate a huge file with redundant css for each component.

The second thing I tried was warp the basic components, like button, lets say a

```
<x-button></x-button>
```

Then in my sass file I include the zurb button file, and make x-button @extends .button or @include .button that make buttons and x-button with the same look. This work for basic elements.

The other way is to applyAuthorStyles and let the css leak

I'm not sure what is the best way, because each approach has its pitfalls.

Why I wrap basic components? To have common behavior and API. For example: enable and disable components, in a form. All my basic components in polymer (x-button, x-input, etc) extends from my framework class, in this framework class I have the common behavior enable and disable, so I can progamattic enable and disable components with the same API.

This is a slow work in proggress, more for fun, and I stop working on this because I need to spend more time creating applications and not creating frameworks. Unfortunately there is no good component framework for Dart as in Javascript like ExtJs and Dojo.

But the Idea was make a component set (with common behavior) and use sass frameworks to the visual effect, maybe abstract the css framework in a way it can be plug and change the look and feel of the application, and that is not easy because some components have specific html markup